# PHP Cron Job Error Local Xampp Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron, xampp

```
How to Set PHP Cron Job ?  
Steps Which I Followed.  
Step 1 : I run below Command.   
swapnil@UBUNTU1:~$ whereis php  
o/p :  
/usr/bin/php 
/usr/bin/php7.0 
/usr/lib/php 
/etc/php 
/usr/share/php7.0-opcache 
/usr/share/php7.0-readline 
/usr/share/php7.0-common 
/usr/share/php7.0-mbstring 
/usr/share/php7.0-zip 
/usr/share/php7.0-xml 
/usr/share/php 
/usr/share/php7.0-json 
/opt/lampp/bin/php 
/usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz

Step 2: I Run Below Command  
swapnil@UBUNTU1:~$ */10 * * * * /usr/lampp/bin/php  
/opt/lampp/htdocs/cron_job/cron.php
```

Error : bash: */10: No such file or directory.
      Here I want to set my cron job locally after every 10 minute

Comment: Is the path to your script correct?

Comment: @RayannNayran. Yes

Comment: Where is your script?

If your script is named 10, rename it to something clearer.

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre, 10 isn't my script name. here 10 denotes my script will run after every 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Your cron is probably good, but you put it at the wrong place.
if you want to test it, try :

```
$ /usr/lampp/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/cron_job/cron.php
```

Then to add it as a CRONTAB, you have to edit the crontab file :

```
$ crontab -e
```

And add it to the end of the file.

for more : https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm

Comment: How ? above command give me output  is 'no crontab for swapnil - using an empty one 888'  After that i  put this line "*/10 * * * * /usr/lampp/bin/php  /opt/lampp/htdocs/cron_job/cron.php".  what is next?

Comment: all is good, you don't need to restart any service. Every 10 minutes your command ' /usr/lampp/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/cron_job/cron.php' will be execute. if you want more explanation [take a look here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm)